# What I have to have for running sqlserver?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a simple code that is using C# and Sqlserver 2008.
For my C# code I get the .EXE file to customer and forced to install the .NET framework on her computer to run just the C# code.

But about the Sqlserver; I have installed the complete Sqlserver on my PC then attached my database on management part of that and am using the Sqlserver

now that I want to get my program to customer I install the .NET framework; but how can I run Sqlserver on her computer and attach the database each time?

Lets me to explain more:

The program will use on a local network and is multi_user.

I installed and am using the Sqlserver on my PC. I created my database and it's tables by help of sqlserver management tool.

for connecting to the datatbase I wrote a code that connect via the users IP address and I tested it on my PC with 2 Virtual machine. It is working truely.

My problem is here:

When I get the program to customer, what I have to do exactly?

What about the database I have to do?
I have to install the whole Sqlserver on customer PC and set that PC as a server or I have a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually trying to re-distribute MS SQL Server 2008 with your application?  Or are you using a re-distributable version?  Or do you want your client installations to connect to a single central SQL server?  This is unclear.

Comment: Do you expect each instance of the program to have a local SQL Server instance running on the same machine? Something smells...

Comment: I am running both the c# and Sqlserver on my PC now. But what I have to do on customers PCs? I have to install the comlete Sqlserver 2008 on theme's PC?

Comment: You can use Sql Server 2008 Express - SQL Server 2008 Express is a free edition of SQL Server that is an ideal data platform for learning and building desktop and small server applications, and for redistribution by ISVs. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1695

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sql server as an embedded database for local storage, use [sql server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx).

If you want your users to have access to a shared database you'll have to instal sql server (sql server express may do) on some machine in their network, configure the access rights, and adjust their connection strings accordingly. Or use SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to install the whole Sqlserver on customer PC and set that PC
>   as a server or I have a better way to do this?

yes you have todo all this work

1)install sql server and the management

2)install your database

3)remote your database to be used

Comment: So I have to install the whole Sqlserver; yes? And waht is your mean about "remote your database to be used"?

Comment: So I have to install the whole Sqlserver : yes? and for remote database : you have to connect to the server from other PCs make a look at this http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/